# 2048 get board with python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create an AI that would play the [2048](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) game. My problem is that I can't get the board in the format I want it.

My code (to get the board):

```
def get_board():
    board = {"1": '-',"2": '-', "3": '-',"4": '-',
            "5": '-',"6": '-', "7": '-',"8": '-',
            "9": '-',"10": '-', "11": '-',"12": '-',
            "13": '-',"14": '-', "15": '-',"16": '-'}
    tiles = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("tile")
    for tl in tiles:
        til = tl.get_attribute("class")       
        tile = til.split()
        if "tile-position-1-1" in tile:
            value = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div")
            board["1"] = value
        elif "tile-position-2-1" in tile:
            value = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div")
            board["2"] = value
        elif "tile-position-3-1" in tile:
            value = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/div")
            board["3"] = value
        return board
```

I want it to put the tiles in the right spot of the dictionary for example:
if tile 1-1 is 4 then it should do `board['1'] = "4"`

Any ideas how I could do that?

Comment: Wouldn't a list of lists be better suited than a dictionary?

Comment: No because of the way the ai works....

Comment: Try re-phrasing this question as a programming problem with a minimal example of what doesn't work. Are you confused about how to read the contents of a webpage using `selenium`, or confused about how to update a dictionary, or looking for data structure advice when it comes to storing the game board?

Comment: How does tile 1-1 translate into ['1']? Where would 1-2 go? and 2-1? You need to simplify what you have provided down to exactly what you are asking, show you have done some work by providing some code, and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: 1-1 is like cords...that's how its in the page but I want to have it like 1-1 is 1, 2-1 is 2, 3-1 is 3,4-1 is 4, then 1-2 is 5, 2-2 is 6.....4-4 is 16 (The problem is that I am pretty new in programming and this is my first time using selenium so I don't know why it didn't work :/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Python but this is Java so hopefully you can translate it.

I put the board into a two-dimensional array of `int` in the form `board[1][2] = 16` where the class on that tile would be `tile tile-16 tile-position-1-2 tile-new`. I know that's not what you asked for but you didn't give enough detail on how you are storing various positions...

```
List<WebElement> tiles = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div.tile"));
int[][] board = new int[5][5]; // need 5 instead of 4 because we are going to use indices 1-4 and not 0-3
for (WebElement tile : tiles)
{
    String className = tile.getAttribute("className");
    String regex = "tile tile-(\\d*) tile-position-(\\d)-(\\d) tile-new";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(className);
    matcher.matches();
    int x = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));
    int y = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
    int value = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    board[x][y] = value;
}
```

The code grabs the DIV with class tile because all tiles that have any value are defined here. (The HTML of the board is kinda weird IMO but I'm not a web designer... so maybe it's just me). It then loops through all tiles and gets the className where all the positional and value data is stored. It uses a Regex to pase the className and then assigns values to the correct position in the array `board`.

If you dump the values of `board` you will get something like

```
0000
0020
0000
0020
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: I will do my best to understand and translate it( I don't know Java) thanks anyway :D

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard... the Selenium based methods should be easily translated. `int[][]` is a two-dimensional array. `for (WebElement tile : tiles)` is like a `foreach()` in other languages. The Regex, I think, will be straightforward since the regex string is apparent, you just need to pull specific matched groups, convert them to `int`, and assign them into the 2d array. Let me know if you need more help than that and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I cant still figure it out but I think I am doing process.....the thing is I don't know whats wrong......I get an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'........when I print(board) I get something like :[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, '2'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, '2', 0, 0, 0]] which has one more digit and one more line....

Comment: So one thing about the way I set it up is that I don't use the 0th index of `board`... use only rows 1-4. That way it matches up with the class names. So loop from x = 1 to 4 and y = 1 to 4 and you should be good. Or you could spend the time -1'ing all the indices... :)

Comment: yeah I figured this out now I just did range(1, 5).....but I still have the other problem....after doing it once if I try to loop it says    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\panag\OneDrive\Python\Finished\Uncompiled\2048\browser auto play\as.py", line 24, in <module>
    game_board = get_board()
  File "C:\Users\panag\OneDrive\Python\Finished\Uncompiled\2048\browser auto play\as.py", line 16, in get_board
    x = int(m.group(3))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: Your best bet is to mark an answer here and look up help with Regex stuff in python. If you can't find the answer, start a new question with your progress and ask for help.